# sqlsrv_connect Login Fails for User

Tags: php, sql-server, wampserver, sql-server-express, sqlsrv

I am attempting to connect to my SQL Server database using PHP. I'm running WampServer, and SQLExpress with its Management Studio. For some reason, calling sqlsrv_connect fails. The connection to SQL Server is opened, but the login fails for user. This happens for both Windows Authentication and SQL Server Authentication. I have already switched to "SQL Server and Windows Authentication Mode" under the "Security" tab of the database properties. I have also checked that remote connections are allowed under the "Connections" tab. I can login using the SQL Server Authentication with Management Studio, just not with the PHP code. Any help on what I maybe doing wrong is appreciated.

```
<?php
$serverName = "STTM-PC\SQLEXPRESS";
$connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"myDatabase","UID"=>"myUsername","PWD"=>"myPassword");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

if ($conn) {
    echo "Connection Established<br/>";
}
else {
    echo "Connection Failed<br/>";
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

Prints out this

```
Connection Failed
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 28000 [SQLSTATE] => 28000 [1] => 18456 [code] => 18456 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'myUsername'. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'myUsername'. ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 42000 [SQLSTATE] => 42000 [1] => 4060 [code] => 4060 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot open database "myDatabase" requested by the login. The login failed. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot open database "myDatabase" requested by the login. The login failed. ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 28000 [SQLSTATE] => 28000 [1] => 18456 [code] => 18456 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'myUsername'. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'myUsername'. ) [3] => Array ( [0] => 42000 [SQLSTATE] => 42000 [1] => 4060 [code] => 4060 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot open database "myDatabase" requested by the login. The login failed. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot open database "myDatabase" requested by the login. The login failed. ) )
```

Comment: I assume you have checked that the user is setup on the database and the password for that use is correct

Comment: Have you enabled remote connections for the sql server? http://blog.citrix24.com/configure-sql-express-to-accept-remote-connections/

Comment: Yes, and I can connect using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio no problem. Just not with PHP. And yes, remote connections are enabled.

Comment: Do you have some error in wamp log?

Comment: No errors in the Wamp PHP, or Apache logs.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out what was wrong. I never the user to the database, and so the connection was not established. To fix, I logged into the database using Management Studio. I went under the "Security" tab, then the "Logins" tab. I right clicked the username, and selected properties. Under "User Mapping", I selected "myDatabase" to map it to this account. Now, the connection is established.